# jQuery image gallery with delete/upload options

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

I've looked through a a dozen different image galleries on the net but due to the very specific requirements I have I decided to post here, because I don't think that google could provide me with a satisfying answer.

Here is a print screen of part of my current project and some simple drawing of what I imagine the gallery should look like :

[image: scetch]

I have empty space on both sides of the page so here are the things that `must have` in the gallery :

1. To be able to position it vertically
2. To be able to delete picture
3. To be able to upload picture
4. To show the real-szie image on the same page

These are the four basic requirements that I need. The number of images will be fixed, and maybe I won't need a scroll, what I find hardly to find is a gallery that offers delete/upload functions, the other things seem pretty standard for almost any gallery around the web.